# Regular expression: match everything except *.TMP

Tags: java, regex

I'm having troubles to create a regular expression who checks if a file has the extention .TMP so the pattern should accept any string who's not equal to (a-z 0-9 or event dots).TMP

To be clear: the matcher should only be succesfull when the file doesn't have the TMP extention.

I've allready found that I need to use (?!expression) for the "not"...

```
(?!.*TMP]) // is wrong ;-)
```

Comment: Why not match `.TMP` and do stuff when it is *not* matched?

Comment: Do you need a regular expression, or do you just need to match files that have a tmp extension?

Comment: The code has to be configured with spring, and I wanted to keep all my options open by using regEx. It must be possible to accept files who start with blabla iso looking at all the files who don't end with .TMP in an other implementation when required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Regular Expression, match everything but](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061651/java-regular-expression-match-everything-but)

Comment: Makes sense.  But in the interest of keeping the Spring context file easy to understand, you might want to consider a method other than regex.  <property name="shouldNotEndWith">.tmp</property> looks nicer than a regex IMO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"(?<!\\.TMP)\\Z"
```

Read: something other than ".TMP" followed by the end of the string.

Comment: "When all you have is a regexp, every problem looks like line noise" -- me ;)

Comment: @msw: The question explicitly asked for a regexp. I don't think it's fair to downvote for answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Agreed. It wasn't to "punish" the poster but to move the answer down the stack (which has happened naturally thus downvote removed). Indeed, the question did ask for a regexp, but sometimes the question is wrong. I don't expect you to necessarily agree with this stance, but I hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (!filename.endsWith(".TMP")) {
     /* then we found a match without using regExp */
}
```

Comment: +1 agree, too trivial a problem to apply regular expressions to.

Comment: +1 but on OS X or Windows you might want to convert the file name to upper case before doing the comparison (case insensitive file systems).

Answer (score 2):

It is not a answer of your question but I think you should look at Apache Common IO which have a bunch of simple methods which can do everything your commonly do. Including finding extensions. Then you simply make a if statement instead of a reg. exp.

http://commons.apache.org/io/

and see the specific java doc for getExtension:
[getExtension JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension(java.lang.String))